# Elasticsearch sum returns a rounded integer value of float field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to get `sum` of fields `price` and `price_department`.

The mapping is:

```
                'completed_order' => [
                    'properties' => [
                        'driver_id'        => [
                            'type'  => 'integer',
                            'index' => 'not_analyzed',
                        ],
                        'order_id'         => [
                            'type'  => 'integer',
                            'index' => 'not_analyzed',
                        ],
                        'price'            => [
                            'type'  => 'float',
                            'index' => 'not_analyzed',
                        ],
                        'price_department' => [
                            'type'  => 'float',
                            'index' => 'not_analyzed',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
```

The problem is that the sum of `price_department` is an integer value. I also tried to get stats of that field. The result is:

```
...'_source' => 
  array (size=6)
    'driver_id' => int 4469
    'price' => float 5.99
    'order_id' => int 2200676
    'price_department' => float 5.99...

...'total_price' => 
  array (size=1)
    'value' => float 5.99
'department_price' => 
  array (size=1)
    'value' => float 5
'department_price_stats' => 
  array (size=5)
    'count' => int 1
    'min' => float 5
    'max' => float 5
    'avg' => float 5
    'sum' => float 5
```

The `aggs` of `body` is:

```
'aggs'  => [
  'drivers' => [
    'terms' => ['field' => 'driver_id','size' => 0,],
    'aggs'  => [
      'total_price' => ['sum' => ['field' => 'price',],],
      'department_price' => ['sum' => ['field' => 'price_department',],],
      'department_price_stats' => ['stats' => ['field' => 'price_department',],],
     ],
   ],
 ],
```

As you can see, `sum` of `price` looks correct but `sum` and `stats` of `price_department` is rounded and returned as an integer.

Comment: Please update your question with the real mapping you have in your index, i.e. the once you get by running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/index`

Comment: Somehow the field price is double and price_department is long. Why could they be changed?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing how you created your index and indexed you documents.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues.

Turned out I had my mappings set to short, needed to use float, double or half_float to get a float return rather than an integer return.

Check your mappings!!